# Is the converse of this also true$?$

Tags: functions, derivatives

If the first derivative of $f$ changes sign at $x$, does $f$ necessarily have an extremum at $x$$?$ I was just wondering about maxima and minima and I thought of this.

I know that if $f'$ changes from positive to negative at $x=a$, then $f$ has a local maximum at $a$ and if $f'$ changes from negative to positive at $x=a$, then the point is a local minimum at $a$ and if $f'$ does not change sign at $x=a$, then $f$ does not have a local extrema at $a$.

Is the converse of the last line also true$?$

Comment: We have that there is a local extremum at $x=a$ if and only if the derivate changes the sign there. This implies that the converse of the last statement is true as well.

Comment: The converse only makes sense if $f$ has a derivative.  Otherwise you get something like "if $f$ does not have a local extremum at $a$ then $f$ cannot be both strictly increasing immediately below $a$ and strictly decreasing immediately above $a$, and $f$ cannot be both strictly decreasing immediately below $a$ and strictly increasing immediately above $a$", something which is intuitively obvious

Comment: I see....thanks

Comment: Nop. Tak for example $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\cos\frac1x\,,\,\,x\neq0\\{}\\0\;,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x=0\end{cases}$$

Then $\;f'(x)\;$ changes sign at $\;x=0\;$ , yet $\;f'(0)\;$ doesn't even exist...and of course, $\;(0,0)\;$ is not an extreme point.

Comment: @DonAntonio - I think "changes sign" was intended to mean that $f'(x)f'(y)<0$ for all $x<a<y$ in some neighbourhood of $a$.

Comment: @mr_e_man And that's what I understood myself as well. Here we have $$f'(x)=\frac1{x^2}\sin\frac1x$$ and this fulfills $\;f'(x)f'(y)<0\;$ for **all**  $\;x<0<y\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio - No, the sine changes sign infinitely many times as $x\to0^+$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Indeed so, as $\;\frac1x\to\infty\;$ when $\;x\to 0^+\;$ , you are right...yet the function fulfills $\;f'(x)f'(y)<0\;$ for infinite values $\;x<o<y\;$ which are arbitrarily to zero (each from its side). That is what I should have written above. Thanks.